# Return ajax updates from asp.net mvc5 action method before returning View

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way ASP.NET MVC action method can return partial status response messages to the view while executing stuff?

Scenario: I have an Ajax form in the view, which on the click of a button, does an Ajax HTTP POST call to the action method. This method does a bunch of stuff - read excel file, insert/update records in sql server, then email.

What I want is the ability to show the user the updates on the view. Say, after the excel file is read, that status should show on the view, then the db work, then emailing. So that the user is aware of what's happening in the action method. But until the mvc action returns there is no way I can do this. Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Generate an ID for the job and have a database table with job status.
- The MVC action creates a new thread to do the work and the ajax call returns immediately.
- The thread processing the job updates the status of the record in the db as work is completed.
- The client uses ajax to poll the database for status changes.

Instead of polling, you could use SignalR, but that may be overkill.

Also, depending on your situation, you may want to implement a job queue instead of having the MVC action start the job thread directly.

Edit - Another thought.. You may be able to have the MVC action do the work synchronously, and periodically send updates back to the client through SignalR. That wouldn't require the overhead of the database, and might be better for a simple case.

Comment: Thanks but this looks like an over kill with the new db and status maintenance. I was hoping to find a easy way like maybe a partial view results intermittently before returning the view. I know it may not exist in MVC today but was trying to look if people had work arounds because this looks like a normal ajax behavior expected out of today's web.

Comment: Okay. I have no knowledge about SignalR but that might be an option. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

How about some more advanced approach with signalR.

In your worker you need

```
Clients.updateGaugeBar(percentage);
```

Method that is called on update in JavaScript

```
var progressHub = $.connection.progressHub;
// Some config work

// Open the connection
$.connection.hub.start();
    progressHub.updateGaugeBar = function (perc) {
      $("#bar").html(GaugeBar.generate(perc));
    };
```

In javascript to show progress (you can use any progress showing method you like). If you do not like percentage you can return any other message you like and show them to the user.

```
   var GaugeBar = GaugeBar || {};
GaugeBar.generate = function (percentage) {
  if (typeof (percentage) != "number")
    return;
  if (percentage > 100 || percentage < 0)
    return;
  var colspan = 1;
  var markup = "<table class='gauge-bar-table'><tr>" +
    "<td style='width:" + percentage.toString() +
    "%' class='gauge-bar-completed'></td>";
  if (percentage < 100) {
    markup += "<td class='gauge-bar-tobedone' style='width:" +
      (100 - percentage).toString() +
      "%'></td>";
    colspan++;
  }
  markup += "</tr><tr class='gauge-bar-statusline'><td colspan='" +
    colspan.toString() +
    "'>" +
    percentage.toString() +
    "% completed</td></tr></table>";
  return markup;
}
```

More detail descriptoion
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx

Comment: This is a bad idea. SignalR is complete overkill for what he is asking for. SignalR is great for when you need to send the same bits of data, in real time, to multiple clients, not just one.

Comment: I would not say that is overkill. You can add user to group and then notify only one user with progress.